# Learning management system software for .NET

Tags: c#, .net, scorm

I am currently investigating open source .NET based solutions for an learning management system (LMS), but am hitting a huge wall. Most folks seem to recommend DotNetSCORM, but not only is their site down for maintenance, but code files I found for it from SourceForge and CodeProject seem to be for **old** alpha/beta builds.

What solutions do you all know of that are out there for LMS's that are both .NET and open source?

Thanks!

Comment: Avoid obscure 3-letter acronyms.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, Hans. Hopefully it's a little more clear what the acronym at least stands for. :P

Comment: `LMS` is in no-way an obscure 3-letter acronym. It is far more known across multiple industries than `PCL` or `PHP`.

Comment: It's sad the LMS software industry seems dead. .Net at least. Even DotNetSCORM website's domain is up for sale.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try http://www.similarsites.com (and similar sites).
Personally I wouldn't go for anything that's down for several days (at least since June 20 according to google cache)

Comment: Unfortunately, that seems like the best solution, even though I basically know nothing about it. :P Not a whole lot of offerings.

Regardless, the link you provided me is **awesome**. I'll dig through there later today. :)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at SharePoint LMS project http://www.sharepointlms.com/

I think it's the most powerful LMS build with .NET

SharePoint LMS is a fully functional LMS based on the Microsoft SharePoint platform. LMS combines most powerful eLearning tools and features such as:

- Learning Path Tracking
- Reports SCORM 1.2 or 2004 compliance   AICC compliance
- Collaborative tools
- Shared Question Pool
- Web conference

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @JohnDoyle Thanks. just added some common info about this LMS